# Finding all PHP files within a certain directory containing a string

Tags: shell

Im wondering if someone can help me out.

Im currently using the following to find all PHP files in a certain directory

```
find /home/mywebsite -type f -name "*.php"
```

How would i extend that to search through those PHP files and get all files with the string base64_decode?

Any help would be great.

Cheers,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
find /home/mywebsite -type f -name '*.php' -exec grep -l base64_decode {} +
```

The `-exec` option to `find` executes a command on the files found. `{}` is replaced by the filename, and the `+` means that it should keep repeating this for all the filenames. `grep` looks for a string in the file, and the `-l` option tells it to print just the filename when there's a match, not all the matching lines.

If you're getting an error from `find`, you may have an old version that doesn't support the `+` feature of `-exec`. Use this command instead:

```
find /home/mywebsite -type f -name '*.php' | xargs grep -l base64_decode
```

`xargs` reads its standard input and turns them into arguments for the command line in its arguments.

Comment: Thanks for that, but i am getting an error msg - find: missing argument to `-exec'